# Chartjs Streaming Plot with persistent data in React single page app

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am using chart.js to plot a realtime data stream in a react single page app. The goal is to be able to navigate to a different page of the app, then return to the page with the plot, and the plot will still be up to date and actively streaming.

Here is the approach I've taken:

```
//App.js

import Plot from "./routes/Plot"
import {useState} from "react"
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom"
import useInterval from "./useInterval"

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(pullInitialData())
    const interval = 10000
    
    function pushData(data) {
        setData(prevData => {
            prevData.push(data);
            return prevData;
        })
    }

    useInterval(() => {pushData({x: Data.now(), y: Math.random()})}, interval)

    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/Plot" element={<Plot data={data} interval={interval}/>}
                    //Other Routes...
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )

}

export default App
```

```
//Plot.js
import { Chart } from 'chart.js'
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2'

function Visualize(props) {
    const duration = 10000*10
    var options = {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'realtime',
                realtime: {
                    ttl: duration*10,
                    duration: duration,
                    refresh: props.interval,
                    delay: 2 * props.interval,
                    pause: false,
                    onRefresh: chart => { chart.update() }
                }
            }
        },
        //other options (including zoom plugin)...
    }

    return (

    <div>
        <Line data={props.data} options={options}
    <div>    

    )

}

export default Plot
```

Please note that this is not the full code being used but I believe it gets the point across. The data is stored in a react state in App. It is updated on an interval that is also handled by App. The data is then passed to the plot object to be plotted. The plot updates itself on refresh but does not explicitly pull data. (This is very similar to the [Push Model](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/latest/guide/data-feed-models.html#push-model-listening-based) defined in the chartjs-plugin-streaming docs).

This works as expected and produces the desired result. On the initial load of the app, pullInitialData fetches the already existing data from a database to populate the plot. This takes care of events such as refreshing the browser as well. The plot data then continues updating even when the app is not at '/Plot'. When the user navigates to '/Plot', the plot displays with the latest data already present and scrolling.

The issue is that the streaming plugin automatically deletes expired data. Since the app is using a react state to store the data, it is unclear to me what happens when chartjs tries to delete data from the data array.

I am hoping that someone can provide an alternative approach that yields the same result but does not rely on potentially dubious usage of a react state. Otherwise, if someone can explain to me why I should *not* be concerned about this, that will also do.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Edit:

Please note also that the structure of the data variable is not a simple array as it appears above. It is of the form:

```
{
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Dataset 1",
            //Other Parameters...,
            data: [],


        }
    ]
}
```

and `pushData` updates only the `data` portion of the object. The true forms are omitted for clarity and to avoid removing attention from the more general approach.